# Tabulator breaks after setData is being called first time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, tabulator

I have a weird bug in my application using `Tabulator` by [@Oli Folkerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588993/oli-folkerd):

After refreshing the table I always end up with having 20 rows instead of my preset 25 rows:

I checked the response from my django `ViewSet` and the answer always contains the right amount of objects.

js Code:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#ptable", 
                          {height:"100%",
                           layout: "fitData",
                           pagination: "local",
                           paginationSize: 25,
                           paginationSizeSelector: [50, 100],
                           ajaxURL: "api/products",                      
                           columns: cols,});

setInterval( function () {
    table.setData(); 
}, 10000);
```

[image]

becomes:

[image]

I am happy to post code on the django part as well, but I do not think thats the problem here. Also interesting: When I click on a random page number in the footer I always get to see 20 items per page - except if I choose the last one.

Comment: Have you tried the remote pagination option? `pagination:"remote"`  http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/page#remote

Comment: Yes I tried that approach, but then I would have to use pagination in my API and the search function would not work easily. Just plugging in `remote` instead of local is not the whole deal if I understood it correctly. The API needs to do the pagination on the server side this way.

Comment: One last thing I can suggest is playing with the `virtualDomBuffer`.  Maybe try using a number greater than your table height.  `virtualDomBuffer: 2000` for example.  I had a rendering issue on a previous application and using a high virtualDomBuffer value fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help :(